# Enviar datos de un input por ajax y onchange

Tags: ajax

Cordial saludo,

Me pueden ayudar por favor, como hago para que: cuando el usuario me llene el input extension automaticamente cuando pase al siguiente input me valide que esa extension no exista en la bd, la idea es no esperar hasta el final que el termine el registro para validar ese campo, con el fin de ahorrarle tiempo al usuario.

He intentado con este codigo pero no me esta capturando el valor del input para poder realizar la validacion.

```js
function verificar() {
  //var valor = $(this).val();
  //var valor = $(this).attr("name");
  //var valor = $("input[name=extension][extension="+X+"]").val();

  var valor = document.getElementById("extension").value;
  //     extension = valor;
  //var valor=$("#extension").val();
  var data = {
    valor: valor // se tiene una variable json y se agrega lo que le vas a mandar, el nombre y el valor
  };

  $.ajax({
    url: "validar.php", //colocas la ruta de donde está el archivo php
    type: "post",
    data: data, //Los datos que se van a enviar por el post en este caso documento
    success: function(response) {
      if (response.trim() == "1") {
        console.log("ya existe");
        console.log(data);
      } else {
        console.log("no existe");
        console.log(data);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
<?php include "conn.php";
$extension=$_POST["data"];
$sql=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM invtelefonos WHERE extension='$extension'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)==0) {
  echo "0"; //ESTO DEVUELVE AL AJAX ESTE VALOR PARA ARROJAR LA RESPUESTA QUE TIENE EL AJAX EN 1.
}

else {
  echo "1";
}

?>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="basicinput">Extensión</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input type="number" onchange="verificar()" pattern="[0-9]{4,4}" name="extension" id="extension" placeholder="" class="form-control span8 tip" maxlength="4" minlength="4" title="Solo numeros. las extensiones son de minimo y maximo 4 numeros" required
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

Con este codigo me arroja esto en consola:
no existe
{valor: ''}

Agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

ya encontre la solucion.

La dejo por si otro lo necesita:

```js
function verificar(extension) {

  var valor = extension;
  var data = {
    valor: valor // se tiene una variable json y se agrega lo que le vas a mandar, el nombre y el valor
  };

  $.ajax({
    url: "validar.php", //colocas la ruta de donde está el archivo php
    type: "post",
    data: data, //Los datos que se van a enviar por el post en este caso documento
    success: function(response) {
      if (response.trim() == "1") {
        console.log("ya existe");
        console.log(data);
      } else {
        console.log("no existe");
        console.log(data);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
<?php include "conn.php";
$extension=$_POST["valor"];
$sql=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM invtelefonos WHERE extension='$extension'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)==0) {
  echo "0"; //ESTO DEVUELVE AL AJAX ESTE VALOR PARA ARROJAR LA RESPUESTA QUE TIENE EL AJAX EN 1.
}

else {
  echo "1";
}

?>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="basicinput">Extensión</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input type="number" onchange="verificar(this.value)" pattern="[0-9]{4,4}" name="extension" id="extension" placeholder="" class="form-control span8 tip" maxlength="4" minlength="4" title="Solo numeros. las extensiones son de minimo y maximo 4 numeros"
      required />
  </div>
</div>
```

Para este codigo tengo 3 archivos. formulario.php script.js y validar.php

En el formulario utilizo onchange="verificar(this.value)" para detectar el valor que me ingresan en el input y pasarlo a script.js por ajax a la consulta en validar.php que me valida que lo que el usuario este ingresando no este en mi BD.